# Where do I put the logic in fragment to interact with the UI? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

So I'm trying to build a github mobile app. I have a bottom navigation which connects to three fragments which are home, profile and settings. So in this home fragment. I have a button that I want to navigate to a new activity and also a button from an image that does an intent to the github website. I also have a recyclerview but it doesn't work. I'm confused on how to make it work on a fragment because previously before I had the bottom navigation I only had an activity and it worked fine. Here is the code for the home fragment. Here is the code to my fragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
private lateinit var rvProfiles: RecyclerView
private var list: ArrayList<Profiles> = arrayListOf()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    rvProfiles = binding.rvGithubProfiles
    rvProfiles.setHasFixedSize(true)

    val githubToolbarButton = binding.toolbar.gitHubLogo
    githubToolbarButton.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.github.com"))
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    val searchDeveloperButton = binding.searchDev
    searchDeveloperButton.setOnClickListener{
        val searchIntent = Intent(context, SearchUsersActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(searchIntent)
    }

    list.addAll(ProfilesData.listData)
    showRecyclerList()
}

private fun showRecyclerList(){
    rvProfiles.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
    val listProfileAdapter = ListProfileAdapter(list)
    rvProfiles.adapter = listProfileAdapter
}
```

}

The full code is in my github repository: https://github.com/briancatraguna/GitHubClone

Comment: The only wrong code I can see is `FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` being called in the wrong place. It should be in `onCreateView` or call `bind` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove initialisation of **binding** from onviewcreated. Do it as below

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    rvProfiles = binding.rvGithubProfiles
    rvProfiles.setHasFixedSize(true)

    val githubToolbarButton = binding.toolbar.gitHubLogo
    githubToolbarButton.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.github.com"))
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    val searchDeveloperButton = binding.searchDev
    searchDeveloperButton.setOnClickListener{
        val searchIntent = Intent(context, SearchUsersActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(searchIntent)
    }

    list.addAll(ProfilesData.listData)
    showRecyclerList()
}
```